# Updating Github Issue Body with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, github, xmlhttprequest, github-api

I've been successfully able to pull an issue, but not update it. My goal is to update the body of the issue with a new string. Per the documentation [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#edit-an-issue) I understand I need to do a "PATCH". This is what I have so far:

```
var patchedIssue = $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'PATCH',
        body: newBodyText,
        url: issueURL,
        success: function(data){
            console.log("success");
        }
});
```

But when I do that in the network tab I see a Status code of 422: Unprocessable Entity. Response message from the API is "Invalid request.For 'links/1/schema', nil is not an object."

If I remove the "body" line I get the same error

Any thoughts? To get the body text I literally did the same as above but with "GET" instead of patch, and then the body text was "patchedIssue.responseJSON.body"

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, needed a "data" key.

This successfully replaced the body text:

```
patchedIssue = $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'PATCH',
        url: issueURL,
        data: '{"body":"test"}',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("success?");
        }
        });
```